# Get Prometheus metrics from flask which is running in kubernates pods

Tags: flask, prometheus

I have integrated Prometheus with my flask application and my application is running in kubernates pods(2 pods).
I have attached same volume for both pods. When i hit "/metrics" endpoint i'm getting single pod data at a time.
is there any way to get the two pods data.